# Error in table of contents with tcolorbox

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

I get the following error message:

```
! error:  (pdf backend): \pdfextension endlink cannot be used in vertical mode
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I tried to make a MWE but I was unable to reproduce the error. So I will try to explain as best as I can.
I have a main file which calls (by inputs) several chapters.
These chapters use tcolorbox for theorems, proofs, ... I use hyperlinks to link the theorems and the proofs (in both ways) with these kinds of macros:

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{prop}{Proposition}{% Proposition
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=prop@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=demop@\thetcbcounter,
    label={prop@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=\chap/Demos/demo-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\demop{\thetcbcounter}{\chap/Demos/demo-\thetcbcounter.tex}}
    }
    {Proposition}
```

and:

```
\NewTotalTColorBox{\demop}{mm}{% Démonstration d'une proposition
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Démonstration de la proposition~\ref{prop@#1},
    hypertarget=demop@#1,hyperlink=prop@#1
    }
    {\input{#2}}
```

And this works fine (or, at least seems to work fine): I click in the theorem, it sends to the corresponding proof (at the end of the chapter) and vice versa.
But I just added at the end of my main file `\tableofcontents` and I get the error message and no pdf.

If I double click on the error (I use TeXstudio), it opens me the toc file. Here are the first lines:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Inégalités dans \R }{1}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {I}La droite numérique}{3}{section.1.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {II}Relations de comparaison}{4}{section.1.2}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {III}Intervalles}{6}{section.1.3}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {III.1}Intervalles de R}{6}{subsection.1.3.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {III.2}Intervalles d'entiers}{7}{subsection.1.3.2}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {IV}Majorants, minorants}{7}{section.1.4}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {V}Plus grand, plus petit élément}{8}{section.1.5}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {VI}Valeur absolue d'un réel}{9}{section.1.6}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {VII}Valeurs approchées}{11}{section.1.7}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {VIII}Droite numérique achevée}{12}{section.1.8}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {IX}Partie entière d'un réel - Approximations décimales}{12}{section.1.9}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {IX.1}Partie entière d'un réel}{12}{subsection.1.9.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {IX.2}Approximations décimales}{13}{subsection.1.9.2}%
\contentsline {section}{\demonstrations }{15}{tcb@cnt@exem.1.2}%
\babel@toc {french}{}\relax 
\babel@toc {french}{}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Rudiments de logique: Assertions et quantificateurs}{27}{chapter.2}%
```

When TeXstudio opens the toc file after double clicking, the line `\contentsline {section}{\demonstrations }{15}{tcb@cnt@exem.1.2}%` is highlighted

I am not sure what I wrote is enough so if anyone tells me he needs more information, I will edit my message

Comment: no that is not enough. Somewhere a link is ended with a \par or similar, but from your description is is quite unclear where, it is even not clear if it is really in the toc.

Comment: Thank you@UlrikeFischer I will try again to create a MWE with this error and I will edit my post. The problem seems to come from the toc because if I comment the line \tableofcontents, there is no error and I get the pdf

Comment: @Didier take a look at these two posts about a similar error as yours: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27385 - describes a fragile command in a section title - and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/What_does_%22%5Cpdfendlink_ended_up_in_different_nesting_level_than_%5Cpdfstartlink%22_mean%3F - explains some background on these low level commands.

Comment: From the latter: do you complile using PDF(La)TeX or LuaLaTeX? The former should give a PDF according to the *Overleaf* link. From the error list you posted, take a look at the entries in Chapter 2. After adding the contentsline for that chapter no sections are entered into the *toc* file.

Comment: Thank you @alchemist I compile using LuaLaTeX. And for the toc file, I just gave the first lines but there are indee entries for sections in chapter 2, chapter 3, … I will study that again tomorrow, because no time today. I have protect commands in some of my title sections (but not all of them) and also texorpdfstring commands

Comment: I don't get it. I wanted to create a MWE. So I modified my main file to input only the first chapter and it compiled normally. So I added the 2nd chapter and it worked fine too. I now added all the chapters and it works fine. Really a mistery for me because I didn't modify any code. Maybe the problem will appear again